# Coinbase API: {\"errors\":[{\"id\":\"invalid_request\",\"message\":\"Invalid currency (USD)\"}]}

Tags: elixir, coinbase-api

```
defmodule APIConnection do
  def process_output({:ok, results}, _) do
    Print.done()
    results.body
  end

  def process_output({:error, results}, api_url) when results.reason == :timeout do
    Print.error("MODULE:#{__MODULE__} - Connection Timeout")
    Print.text("Redialing . . . ")
    fetch(api_url)
  end

  def process_output({:error, results}, _) do
    IO.inspect(results.reason)
  end

  def fetch(api_url) do
    HTTPoison.start()
    HTTPoison.get(api_url, [], ssl: [{:versions, [:"tlsv1.2"]}])
  end

  def go(api_url) do
    # api_url = "https://api.coinbase.com/v2/exchange-rates"
    fetch(api_url)
    |> process_output(api_url)
  end
end
```

Error Message:

```
"{\"errors\":[{\"id\":\"invalid_request\",\"message\":\"Invalid currency (USD)\"}]}"
```

According to https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#get-currencies, https://api.coinbase.com/v2/exchange-rates is the correct endpoint for exchange data. That said, what's causing this error and how is it efficiently resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me:

```
iex(1)> APIConnection.go("https://api.coinbase.com/v2/exchange-rates")                                                 │ 18     HTTPoison.get(api_url, [], ssl: [{:versions, [:"tlsv1.2"]}])
done                                                                                                                   │ 19   end
"{\"data\":{\"currency\":\"USD\",\"rates\": ...
```

Maybe it was a temporary error with their API. I can reproduce it by calling the API with an invalid currency, but not `USD`:

```
$ curl https://api.coinbase.com/v2/exchange-rates?currency=USD
{"data":{"currency":"USD","rates":{

$ curl https://api.coinbase.com/v2/exchange-rates?currency=XXX
{"errors":[{"id":"invalid_request","message":"Invalid currency (XXX)"}]}
```

Comment: Yup, looks like it was a temporary issue. It's all good now. Thanks for your input :)